# WebStorm and Git: How to find diffs between two commits?

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

This is Git window in WebStorm:

[image]

In the left-hand side, you can see all the commits. When I click on a certain commit I get in the right-hand side of the screen the list of files that have been changed with relation to one commit backwards.

I want to compare between the latest commit and **some other commit** (not necessarily the one before). Do you know how to do it using **WebStorm GUI**?

I know the git command 'git diff  ', but I want to see the differences using WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

This what is given in the documentation.
Use the **Show Diff** command on the context menu of a file to explore the differences between branches.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html#d58108e85

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/comparing-files.html